# How do I check for value existence / why is ResultSet closed in SQLite?

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc, resultset

## Setup

I am using `JDBC SQLite` for my server database.

## What I am trying to do

I want to check if a value (for example an `ID` or a `username`) already exists in a table.

## My Code

```
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("select * from " + tableName + " where " + columnName + "=? limit 1");
preparedStatement.setString(1, value);
ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
resultSet.next();
try { // this was just for testing and is dumb because it prints an error every time the value does not exist.
      // my code actually wasn't wrong. I just tested it badly .. 
      // it's replacable with if (resultSet.next())
    resultSet.getString(1);
    System.out.println("check true");
    return true;
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("check false");
    return false;
}
```

Here I want to check if a specific `value` already exists in my `column(Name)` in my `table`.

## The Problems

This code will always throw a `SQLException`: "ResultSet closed" at `resultSet.getString(columnName)`. It does not matter if the value already exists in the table or not. My query could also be wrong because I don't get what I should put after `select`. I had a `1` there once, but everyone was using `*` for "all" and it changed nothing. I seriously don't get [this](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html) because it is too complicated for me and I just wanted to know what the argument after `select` does..

## Approaches

I tried many things and read a lot of threads, but the only thing I came across was that I need to first call `resultSet.next()` and that the `ResultSet` won't throw `ResultSet closed` exception that way, but it didn't change anything.
If there is a better way to check if a value already exists in a table, please tell me.

## Visualisation

[image: a table]
I have a table here (the `NULL`'s don't matter they could be some random values) and I want to check `ggffvgvg` exists or not.

## Complete StackTrace

```
java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet closed
at org.sqlite.core.CoreResultSet.checkOpen(CoreResultSet.java:69)
at org.sqlite.core.CoreResultSet.markCol(CoreResultSet.java:96)
at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3ResultSet.getString(JDBC3ResultSet.java:436)
at Database.check(Database.java:50)
at ClientHandler.run(ClientHandler.java:72)
```

Comment: You have enclosed your column name in single quotes, turning it into a string literal.

Comment: before that I got "column columnName does not exist" exception even though it does

Comment: I would always wrap the ResultSet.next() call into a if. It returns true, if there actually is a new line that was read. Only then read values from the resultset

Comment: You can also just read values by giving the getter the number of the column (starting with 1) like `resultSet.getString(1)` -> as you only select 1 column, it will always be the right one

Comment: Perhaps try wrapping the column name in double quotes (`"`) instead of single quotes.

Comment: @MichaelRitter I just did it like that to get a `StackTrace` because it would never work... even if the value existed

Comment: @GordThompson I changed the code and updated my question, but I get the same "ResultSet closed" error as before

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot what does resultSet.next() return? is it always false? if so, either your tablename or columnname is wrong, or the database doesn't contain the given value

Comment: You could even just simply return the result of `resultSet.next()` as its false if no row exists and true if at least (and due to the limit also at most) one row exists

Comment: @MichaelRitter it is always false. That was my question. I put `tableName` and `columnName` just like in my "create table" table statement and in my sqlite viewer the value exists. So I bet my query is wrong..

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot did you write your changes to the database to the file (from the external program)? Otherwise the db is probably still empty and therefore java doesn't find the row

Comment: @MichaelRitter no, I of course did not. I am inserting it through my client and that works fine, but this part does not work.

Comment: Just to clarify my last comment: SQLite (other than MySQL and similar) doesn't have a server, that writes to the file as soon as it gets a insert request. Each program connecting to it has so store the changes manually (java JDBC does that for you unless you have autocommit turned off). So if you inserted the row in your "client" which i guess is that 3rd party database editor and you didn't press save there, the database file didn't receive those changes yet (as they are only local in the db editor)

Comment: I didn't save it.. I wrote it :) I can also write in SQLiteviewer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`resultSet.next()` returns a boolean which tells you whether there is a next record or not.  Ignoring this returned value is like shooting your own foot with a rocket launcher.

So, if the value you are looking for is not in the result set, (either because it really isn't, or because you did not ask for it properly,) `resultSet.next()` *will* return `false`, and your code *will* blow up with the exception that you are receiving.

Your `resultSet.getString(1)` clause will fetch the first column in the result set, (if there is a current row,) and it will return it to you ***assuming*** that it is in fact a string.  The first column of most tables is usually an integer, or some other kind of key data type, which means that it is rarely a string.  If you are lucky, it will be something that the JDBC driver can convert to a string, but you are tempting your fate by assuming that.

If you are only going to check the value of a single column, then your query statement must select that column only. This means that instead of

`"select * from " + tableName + " where " + columnName + "=? limit 1"`

you must do

`"select " + columnName + " from " + tableName + " where " + columnName + "=? limit 1"`

However, if I understand correctly what you are trying to achieve, you do not even need to fetch the field and check its value.  Simply the `true` or `false` result of `resultSet.next()` should suffice.

Comment: Yea I told him that in the comments as well... there seems to be another problem (`.next()` always returning false)

Comment: It works now. Nothing was wrong with my code, but I just tested it wrong. I just accepted your answer because it is the only one and my problem is solved. Actually @MichaelRitter solved it for me because in a comment he pointed out that I may have used my SQLite viewer in a wrong way ( not restarting my server / updating the database on the server ). I just put the try catch code because I wanted to see if there is an error and to get some feedback. I know that I could have just put (if (resultSet.net()) and also it doesn't matter if I put a `*` or my `columnName`. Thank you mates!

Comment: @MichaelRitter If you would like to turn your comment into an answer, then the OP could perhaps un-accept mine and accept yours.